# Program not working on win, but working on mac. why?

Tags: c++, windows-7, text-files

I have problem with my university homework. The program which needs to edit text from one line text to a paragraph where in each line is not more than 80 symbols. You can make a line break only after space, '.', ',' etc.

This code is working properly on mac, but it doesn't work on my win7. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i=0;
    char symbol[80];
    fstream fin ("in.txt", ios::in);
    fstream fout ("out.txt", ios::out);
    fin.get(symbol[i]);
    while(!fin.eof()){
        if(symbol[i] == '\n' || i == 80) {
            while(symbol[i] != ' ' && symbol[i] != ',' && symbol[i] !='?' && symbol[i] != '.' && symbol[i] !='!' && symbol[i]!='(' && symbol[i] !=')'){
                i--;
                fin.seekg(-1, ios::cur);
            }
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                fout.put(symbol[j]);
            }
            fout.put('\n');
            i = -1;

        }
        i++;
        fin.get(symbol[i]);
    }
    if (fin.eof()){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            fout.put(symbol[j]);
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ", but it doesn't work " - not very helpful

Comment: Have you rebuilt it under Windows or were you expecting the same executable to work on both platforms?

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? Fails to compile? Compiles, but throws some errors or garbage when running? Or maybe it runs, but behaves incorrectly? You should be more specific with "doesn't work".

Comment: @Janis: what is it _supposed_ to do? What does it _actually_ do? These are two pieces of information that should be in _every_ problem report.

Comment: (1) Please specify what "doesn't work" means. (2) Add error handling to your code. (What if you cannot open the files? You don't check for that.) (3) Ideally, reduce your code to max. half the lines so that it's still showing the problem. The less code, the more people will look closely at it.

Comment: Note that your code will fail on any platform if you give it an input of 80 characters or more containing no word breaks.

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify how "it doesn't work" and I haven't studied your code (It doesn't look like you've taken the time to reduce it to the minimum required to reproduce your problem, so [TL;DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR)). You could well be experiencing a [Newline problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems), given the platforms you mention..

On Microsoft platforms, a new-line is Carriage Return (`CR`, `0x0D` or `\r`) followed by Line Feed (`LF`, `0x0A` or `\n`). You're only looking for LF.

(Presumably, once-upon-a-time, MicroSoft's Disk Operating System ran on mechanical typewriters and the operator would have to return the carriage to the beginning before moving to the next line).

Comment: +1, not because I am sure you're right, but because I thought of a *Newline problem* myself when I read the question...

Comment: `'\n'` is the entire line break, however it is represented in the external file.

Answer (score 0):

"fseek" and several other bits and pieces in this code are unix-like operations.
Windows is not a unix-like machine (whereas Mac is).

If you install cygwin on your machine it will add those and may just solve your problem for you.

Alternatively, you could be suffering from this problem:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/129839-fseek-broken-under-windows.html

We're all kind of guessing here, though, as you haven't provided enough information for us to actually know what problem you're really having.

Comment: fseek is part of standard C, she's using a C++ fstream, and cygwin has nothing to do with either. Still given the question I can't justify a downvote, besides cygwin _is_ cool.

Comment: :) thanks. cygwin is cool - but if it's not the problem then I guess my answer is useless. It was just another stab in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that I see in the code (which might or might not be the cause of the problem):
What if in a given line you have only normal characters (no spaces, questions, exclamantion marks etc)?

Then, if I am reading this correctly, your innermost while-loop will go beyond the beginning of your string and start processing some garbage. Also, as a result, you might incorrectly seekg in your file stream.